# Cannot make latex multicolumn work

Tags: math-mode, tables, arrays

I am trying to make a matrix in LaTeX.
Now I am trying to make a table with multicolumn like

```
a b c
d  у
```

So I coded

```
\usepackage{arydshln}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{multirow}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
& \hspace{0.3cm}\overbrace{\hphantom{\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c
\end{array}}}\\
&\left[
\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c\\
d&\multicolumn{2}{c}{$\phi$}\\
\end{array}
\right]
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

But I cannot make the multicolumn work 
I've read several manuals like

http://andrewjpage.com/index.php?/archives/43-Multirow-and-multicolumn-spanning-with-latex-tables.html

http://cosy.comli.com/wordpress1/2009/04/08/advanced-matrix-partitioning-latex/

And some others, but it doesn't solve my problem. I am using texmaker and it error log gives some abstract errors like "`missing $ inserted`".
Thank you.

Comment: This is a question better suited for http://tex.stackexchange.com. That said, I _think_ you need to insert a space before the closing `$`, like this: `$\phi $`.

Comment: @Matt Ball (although it probably not going to reach stackoverflow): you don't need a space before the closing dollar.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You already are in math environment (`align*`), so there's no need to escape `\phi` with `$ $` -- and that's what is causing the error. Just remove them, and you should be good to go.